# Proof Reversible quantum gate is linear

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

[image]

Edit: to avoid confusion, this problem should start off my assuming the input bits and output bits are classical and just try all the possible combinations of constants to show linearity.

Comment: I don't think this problem has anything to do with quantum gates.  Try to write down all reversible classical gates from 2 to 2 bits and show that they are of this form.  (You seem to have *started* from this form?)

Comment: Thanks man.. sorted ! So, guys if you are interested in this problem.. I totally misinterpreted the question, the bits are classical and we just have to find all the possible matrix that can carry out a gate operation has non-zero determinant i.e. invertible.

Comment: You should feel free to write an answer to your own question -- this is explicitly allowed and encouraged!